# Victory Area chart bottom stroke

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

Any ideas how to add a bottom stroke to Victory Area:

[image]

```
<VictoryArea
    style={{
       data: { fill: "#c43a31", stroke: "blue", strokeWidth: 3 }
    }}
...
```

It is possible to create another layer with the bottom range data set, but it will also add unnecessary complexity to the chart

Comment: Sadly, no. Ended up not using the stroke